# PL/SQL, cx_Oracle: How do I map a user-defined record onto a python result type

Tags: plsql, cx-oracle

I'm trying to get a python result from this PL/SQL code:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE MyRecord IS RECORD (
        state    NUMBER,
        text     VARCHAR2(32),
        dt       DATE
    );
    TYPE MyRecordTable IS TABLE OF MyRecord;
    recordTable MyRecordTable;
    result MyRecordTable;
FUNCTION peek RETURN MyRecordTable
IS
    recordTable MyRecordTable;
BEGIN
    recordTable := MyRecordTable();
    recordTable.extend;
    recordTable(recordTable.last).state := 4711;
    recordTable(recordTable.last).text := 'Test';
    RETURN recordTable;
END;
BEGIN
    :result := peek;
END;
```

I cannot use row type cursors, as in my actual PL/SQL code, there are calls to functions, the results of which I want to put into such a table of user records. Is that possible?
My Python code looks like this:

```
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(server, port, sid)
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user, pw, dsn)
# Maybe there's a way using an output type handler?
conn.outputtypehandler = output_type_handler
cursor = conn.cursor()
result = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.OBJECT)
cursor.execute(PLSQL, result = result)
# This would be nice, if it worked:
#result = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: You would like to return some kind of a collection from your PLSQL procedure? I mean return multiple columns.

Comment: Yes: I just can't figure out, how to bind a table of user-defined records to a python (collection) type.

Comment: @Murat.Gurol Were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: @matthewm I'm afraid, no. It somewhat lost it's relevance ;)